# Displaying Script on Success with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this script (does a document.write, you can visit the src to see it), which spends time loading as soon as it is reached in the HTML sequence of my pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pkmncards.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=25"></script>
```

This prevents anything after the script from loading for a second or two while it loads, so instead I want to load it via jQuery Ajax to prevent the hangup.

Here's what I've attempted:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j.ajax({
        url: "http://pkmncards.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=25",
        dataType: "script",
        success: function (data) {
            $j("#recent-discussion").html(data)
        }
    });
});
```

However I'm not handling the success properly. I see the request load, but it doesn't do anything. I want it to run the script and output the document.write into the target #recent-discussion.

I'm still searching for examples but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can't you simply move the `script` tag to the bottom?

Comment: You are turning a data type of "script" which is not HTML.

Comment: You're getting from datatype: "script" but trying to load the data directly as the html of a div? are you actually receiving a script, or is it html?

Comment: How about trying the async attribute on your script tag

Comment: @mgibsonbr I can only move it down so far, it displays HTML and I need that HTML in a certain place.

Comment: @DavidDraughn I guess I am receiving the script. That's the problem.

Comment: @Musa Thank you for the idea, but it does not seem to be working with this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute `document.write` after the page is loaded. Any script that you load via an AJAX call that uses `document.write` will not work correctly.

Comment: I think it might be a combination of this plus the fact that I'm trying to turn a script into HTML. Thank you for the responses everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call seems correct, and you don't actually need to do anything in the `success` callback - the script will have already started executing by then ([but not necessarily so](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)).

If it's not working, then check whether or not it was loaded correctly (maybe using an `error` callback in the ajax call). BTW is this script in the same domain as your main page? You can load scripts from different domains, but you can't normally make ajax calls to them (due to the same-origin policy).

> I want it to run the script and output the document.write into the target #recent-discussion.

I don't think that's actually possible... If that's what your script need to do, and you can't change it, I'm afraid there's little you can do (short of monkey-patching `document.write`, that is).

Comment: Script is on a third party domain... yet another goof on my part.